# Pipe an array of lines into command exec in Go?

Tags: bash, go, pipe

I have an array of paths that I would like to pipe into another command.

For example, say I have the following array of paths of unknown length `N`:

```
file1.mp4
file2.mp4
file3.mp4
fileN.mp4
```

That are stored in a `[]string`

Of which, I am trying to pipe into the following command:

```
mpv --playlist=-
```

Resulting in:

```
file1.mp4 file2.mp4 file3.mp4 fileN.mp4 | mpv --playlist=-
```

So that an mpv instance is launched playing the files in order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go - write to stdin on external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382880/go-write-to-stdin-on-external-command), [how can I get stdin to exec cmd in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166468/how-can-i-get-stdin-to-exec-cmd-in-golang),[Pipe string into STDIN of command in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49900996/pipe-string-into-stdin-of-command-in-golang).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Steffen, for leading me in the right direction.

Here's my solution:

```
var str string
for _, path  := range paths {
    str += path + "\n"
}

cmd := exec.Command("mpv", "--playlist=-")
cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(str)

err := cmd.Run()
```

Comment: `cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(strings.Join(paths, "\n"))`